# How to publish a asp.net web core application on own hosting windows

Tags: asp.net-core, publish

I have a taken a windows hosting that can run web core 2 applications. I have published first the application to a folder on my pc and then moved the files to a folder on the hosted web site. When I access the folder via http I get the following error message:

```
 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
Common causes of this issue:

    The application process failed to start
    The application process started but then stopped
    The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port 

Troubleshooting steps:

    Check the system event log for error messages
    Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
    Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

This is a basic application without database, it's the "Hello World" empty Template of Visual Studio. I did this for a test.
The web provider says it does not depend from them. I have no way to know what is going wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can read this blog http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx. It seems that you havent published your application properly.

Based on my experience, to resolve above error, you need to publish the website/project as a self-contained application. In order to publish it as a self-contained application, please add this to the csproj folder.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;win7-x86;ubuntu.16.04-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<SuppressDockerTargets>True</SuppressDockerTargets>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Hope this help!